# how to switch sandbox account in iOS device

Tags: in-app-purchase

Now I am login apple using a new sandbox account, when I am using in app purchase. It still using the old account. I have tried:

- close the app and reopen it and do in app purchase, but still popup UI using the old sandbox account
- reinstall the app and do in app purchase, but still using the old sandbox account
- tried in another ios device(iPhone XR) using the new sandbox account(the app still using the old official app id)

what should I do to switch to the new sandbox account? By the way, I am using iPad, and the software version: 14.6.

Comment: Yes，I have logged out.@fsb

Comment: I am using real device. @fsb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since iOS 12, the sandbox account are seperate management. In the setting-App Store-Sandbox account, you can manage and switch the sandbox account.

Answer (score 1):

The app that you are trying to use is "licensed" to the account that purchased it, ie: the old account.

You will have to download that app again under the new account in order to properly use it.

Comment: I already tried reinstall the app(I have login using new sandbox account).@ErniePC12 but it still did not work